# Ruby example to access google shopping api using GAN publisher id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-api-client

I was wondering if anyone could provide an example of how to pull products from the Google Shopping API using a GAN publisher ID and ruby (google-api-ruby-client).  I'm gathering you need to authenticate using oauth. The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/v1/getting_started.html#gan-notes) is very sparse so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Found a good example using curl here if anyone is interested http://humbuckercode.co.uk/licks/code/google-search-api-for-shopping/

Comment: Don't use that. ClientLogin is not recommended and you should be using the official client anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Basic usage of the shopping API with the client is easy.

```
require 'google/api_client'

client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization = nil

shopping = client.discovered_api("shopping", "v1")
result = client.execute(:api_method => shopping.products.list,
                        :parameters => { "source" => "public" })
```

To query by GAN publisher ID, you need to be authenticated as you're aware. You can use OAuth 2 for that. You can see a sample of that for the ruby client at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2. The scope to use for shopping is:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/shoppingapi
```

You can use the APIs explorer to try this out pretty quickly:

```
http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=shopping&_v=v1&_m=products.list
```

Answer (score 0):

With version 0.9.11 is even easier

```
require 'google/apis/content_v2'

def list_products
  content_for_shopping = Google::Apis::ContentV2::ShoppingContentService.new
  content_for_shopping.authorization = get_authorization(%w(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content))
  content_for_shopping.authorization.fetch_access_token!

  content_for_shopping.list_products(ENV['GOOGLE_MERCHANT_CENTER_ID'])
end

def get_authorization(scopes)
  cert_path = Gem.loaded_specs['google-api-client'].full_gem_path + '/lib/cacerts.pem'
  ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = cert_path
  authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
  # Clone and set the subject
  auth_client = authorization.dup
  return auth_client
end
```